# How to assign multiple values from a map in a loop in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a map in groovy where each item has multiple values that I need to use in a loop. The number of values is fixed, so could be stored in a list/array, tuple - does not matter.

Example, I tried:

```
def routemap = [ One: ['Berlin','Hamburg'], Two: ['London','Paris'], Three: ['Rome','Barcelona']]

routemap.each { route, startend ->
    println "Route: $route"
    println "Start: $startend[0] End: $startend[1]"
}
```

This does not provide the desired result, the list index does not work.

```
Route: One
Start: [Berlin, Hamburg][0] End: [Berlin, Hamburg][1]
Route: Two
Start: [London, Paris][0] End: [London, Paris][1]
Route: Three
Start: [Rome, Barcelona][0] End: [Rome, Barcelona][1]
```

Also I am wondering if there is a better, more elegant way to do it? Is there a way to assign two values (or a pair or tuple like in Python) instead of "startend" in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You should put `$startend[index]` in the curly brackets, like `${startend[0]}`. So your code will look like that:

```
def routemap = [ One: ['Berlin','Hamburg'], Two: ['London','Paris'], Three: ['Rome','Barcelona']]

routemap.each { route, startend ->
    println "Route: $route"
    println "Start: ${startend[0]} End: ${startend[1]}" // here is the change
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works - any idea on a nicer / more elegant solution using tuples (instead of the hardcoded hack with indices)?

Comment: If the you do not like indexes you may use first/last: `println "Start: ${startend.first()} End: ${startend.last()}"` But that's probably not an elegant solution. Maybe look here: https://blog.mrhaki.com/2016/03/groovy-goodness-using-tuples.html You can use `Tuple2` class. Then you could do: `println "Start: ${startend.first} End: ${startend.second}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can literally use the multiple assignment for the `startend` argument:

```
def routemap = [ One: ['Berlin','Hamburg'], Two: ['London','Paris'], Three: ['Rome','Barcelona']]

routemap.each{ route, startend ->
  def ( start, end ) = startend
  println "Route: $route"
  println "Start: $start End: $end"
}
```

prints

```
Route: One
Start: Berlin End: Hamburg
Route: Two
Start: London End: Paris
Route: Three
Start: Rome End: Barcelona
```